# python nested list comprehension string concatenation

Tags: python, list-comprehension, nested-lists

I have a list of lists in python looking like this:

```
[['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd']]
```

I want to come up with a string like this:

```
a,b;c,d
```

So the lists should be separated with a `;` and the values of the same list should be separated with a `,`

So far I tried `','.join([y for x in test for y in x])` which returns `a,b,c,d`. Not quite there, yet, as you can see.

Comment: "So the lists should be separated with a ; and the values of the same list should be separated with a ," - that's not a python list then. It's a string

Comment: `';'.join(','.join(xs) for xs in lst)`

Comment: yes, the final output should be a string. will update the question accordingly to make that clear.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
";".join([','.join(x) for x in a])
```

Comment: my actual data contains float values :/
and python now errors `TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, float found`...

Comment: okay in that case i need to use this code: `";".join([','.join(map(str, x)) for x in value])`

Answer (score 7):

```
>>> ';'.join(','.join(x) for x in [['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd']])
'a,b;c,d'
```

Answer (score 1):

To do it functionally you could use map:

```
l = [['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd']]


print(";".join(map(".".join, l)))
a.b;c.d
```